# From standing matter waves of the atoms to Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, history

I read in the Resnick - Halliday Physics textbook (2nd edition):

> "The idea that stable states in atoms correspond to standing matter waves was adopted by Erwin Schrodinger in 1926 and used by him as the foundation of wave mechanics..."

What was Schrodinger's main reasoning which from stable states of atoms led him to wave mechanics?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more appropriate for the History of Science.

Comment: Just to be clear, "History of Science" means our sister site [HSM.SE].

Answer (score 3):

> [Adopting a proposal made by Louis de Broglie](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Erwin-Schrodinger) in 1924 that particles of matter have a dual nature and in some situations act like waves, Schrödinger introduced a theory describing the behaviour of such a system by a wave equation that is now known as the Schrödinger equation. The solutions to Schrödinger’s equation, unlike the solutions to Newton’s equations, are wave functions that can only be related to the probable occurrence of physical events. The definite and readily visualized sequence of events of the planetary orbits of Newton is, in quantum mechanics, replaced by the more abstract notion of probability.

Answer (score 1):

It was De Broglies matter wave theory, as did Anna already say. Niels Bohr was furious about the Schrödinger model, because he thought that only his model would correctly explain the atomic resonance spectra (Lyman series aso.) and Schrödinger's model wouldn't, but actually both models are able to calculate it.

If someone wonders why Bohr didn't accept the Schrödinger model is because at first, De Broglies matter waves were a hypothesis at best when Schrödinger created his model. It was only experimentally confirmed afterwards by G.P. Thomson in 1926 and by C. Davisson and L. H. Germer in 1927.

Heisenberg then came with this "quantum egg", the uncertainty principle, in order to prove his tutor Bohr's model right. It's a mathematically correct, but semantically very crappy theory that doesn't make too much sense. But Schrödinger's waves are mostly mathematical too, because he never explained, when calculating the particle in a box, what that "box" really is supposed to be, because there is no box in reality, is there?

After that the thirties started and the scientists like the whole Western society had other, rather political problems to deal with than scientific models and their discussions. That's why these models stalled back then. And string theory is currently stalling too, so "[Im Westen nichts Neues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Quiet_on_the_Western_Front)".

Comment: Μore specifically I am looking for the main reasoning that, according to the excerpt from the Resnick - Halliday book I quote, led Schrodinger from the  **stable states of atoms** to wave mechanics.

Comment: Oh, he did start with the Bohr model, which is mathematically correct indeed. This means that the Schrödinger model gets to the same values as Bohr, just by the "particle in a box" model. Have a look [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/schr.html#c1) and [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Physical_Chemistry_(LibreTexts)/03%3A_The_Schrodinger_Equation_and_a_Particle_in_a_Box/3.05%3A_The_Energy_of_a_Particle_in_a_Box_is_Quantized). You can calculate the atomic resonance spectra (aka energies) with both models well.

Comment: The states or orbitals themselves are purely of mathematical nature in the Schrödinger wave model. However, it was Bohr's idea to explain the atomic resonance spectra with his "planet around the sun" analogy. Schrödinger then made the same just with standing waves, inventing the "particle in a box" model, which are actually 'waves' in a box, not real particles. [This little treat](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/Schr2.html) might help as well.

Comment: Marcus: Your comment "Schrödinger then made the same just with standing waves, inventing the "particle in a box" model, which are actually 'waves' in a box, not real particles." looks very helpful!

Comment: Thanks. I extended my answer a bit, because everything in science must be seen in its historical context as well...